# Django: reencode request and call another view

Tags: django, oauth2-toolkit

I am working on a backend application that exposes a JSON-based REST api. However, I am using some library that has some of its own endpoints and they accept form-endcoded data. I want to extend the actions done by those endpoints and expose my extended versions. At the same time, I want my API to be consistent and I want all my endpoints to use JSON. To be more specific, I use the oauth2_provider library, and I want to logout users when they revoke a token. I am also considering making a `logout` handle that would require the bearer token in the `Authorization` header and would both logout the user and revoke the token.

My first approach to this was to write a wrapper view around the `oauth2_toolkit` revoke token view, loggging the user out in the wrapper view and then calling the actual revoke_token view. However, I have to modify the body of the request, which is immutable.

```
class Logout(View):
   def get(self, request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
           logout(request)
       # modify the .body attr of the request or create a new request here
       RevokeTokenView.as_view(request)
```

I couldn't find a way to clone a Django request or modify it. Is there a way to do it? 
(For now I am looking into creating a custom oauthlib_backend_class, but it feels as a bit of an overkill)

**UPD**: the data that is required by the `revoke_token` view is in the `request_body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the immutable request body like below:

```py
class Logout(View):
   def get(self, request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
           logout(request)
       # modify or create a new request here
       body = request.GET.copy()
       body['key'] = 'new_value'
       request.GET = body
       RevokeTokenView.as_view(request)
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to change `.body` attribute of the request object, according to [django's implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L312), you should change the `._body` attribute which is a private attribute of the `request` object.

Comment: The problem is that the params are not in GET or POST, they are in the .body . I will update my question